# constraint on static fields and type inference

Tags: haxe

Is it possible to have constraint on static fields in Haxe? For example we may have classes which have static field `instance` of type of corresponding class. And we may want a function that will return an instance of class passed as parameter. This is my attempt:

```
class Foo {
    static public var instance = new Foo();
    function new() {}
}

class Test {
    // get instance from every class that have static field instance 
    static function getInstance<T, ClassT:({instance:T}, Class<T>)>(t:ClassT):T {
        return t.instance;
    }

    static function main() {
        var a = getInstance(Foo);
        $type(a); //Test.hx:14: characters 14-15 : Warning : Unknown<0>
    }
}
```

but it fails, because [type parameter constraints are checked lazily](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/6144). Any ideas on how do this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a typedef?

Heres a quick edit of your code showing the basic idea

```
typedef HasInstance = {
    var instance:Dynamic;
}

class Foo {
    static public var instance = new Foo();
    function new() {}
}

class Bar {
    static public var instance = new Bar();
    function new() {}
}

class Test {
    // get instance from every class that have static field instance 
    static function getInstance<T:HasInstance>(t:T):T {
        trace(t);
        return t.instance;
    }

    static function main() {
        var a = getInstance(Foo);
        trace(a);
        $type(a);
        var b = getInstance(Bar);
        trace(b);
        $type(b);
    }
}
```

example on [try haxe!](http://try.haxe.org/#099f0)

You would change the instance type within the typedef to be more appropriate for your needs, and you can also constrain typedefs too, which can be very useful

Comment: That just does not work. In your example `a` is of type `Class<Foo>`but actual value of `a` is of type `Foo`. This will end in runtime errors.

Comment: This is the best solution, but you can use a generic instead of Dynamic.  
http://try.haxe.org/#6cc96

Comment: I really like the solution from @kobi7 Isn't it worth converting to answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using macro, here is a possible solution:
http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#7d650

Foo.hx

```
class Foo {
    static public var instance = new Foo();
    public var foo:Int;
    function new() {}
}

class Test {

    macro static function getInstance(e) return Macro.getInstance(e);

    static function _getInstance<T, ClassT:({instance:T}, Class<T>)>(t:ClassT):T 
        return t.instance;

    static function main() {
        var a = getInstance(Foo);
        $type(a);
    }
}
```

Macro.hx

```
import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.Context.*;
using tink.MacroApi;

class Macro {
    public static function getInstance(e:Expr) {
        var ct = TPath(e.toString().asTypePath());
        return macro (Test._getInstance($e):$ct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it easier just do like this, if using macro: `macro static function getInstance<T>(e:ExprOf<Class<T>>):ExprOf<T> return macro $e.instance;`

Comment: Sure, I just try not to move everything into macro, so you can expand the function, if needed,  without going into macro code.